# Condicionales avanzados Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Suponiendo que tengo una celda que contiene Nombre  y nombre medio de esta forma
"Daniel Jesus" quiero extraer el primer nombre : "Daniel"  y en dado caso que la celda solo tenga  "Daniel" quiero  tomar ese valor

ejemplo:

```
        1
 ____________________
A|  Daniel Jesus    |   espero obtener     "Daniel"
 |__________________|


        1
 ____________________
A|  Daniel          |   espero obtener     "Daniel"
 |__________________|
```

Estoy Usando la siguiente formula:

```
=(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

y esto me funciona para el primer caso en mis ejemplos pero no en el el segundo caso  ya que si no encuentra un espacio despues del "Daniel"   me marca error.

Como puedo obtener el resultado que espero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He utilizado esto y parece funcionar:

```
=SI(ESERROR(HALLAR(" ";A1));A1;IZQUIERDA(A1;HALLAR(" ";A1)))
```

> **Tener presente que tengo mi excel en español, por lo que los nombres de las funciones pueden variar.*

Básicamente lo que hice fue hacer uso de la función "EsError" para ver si la parte que busca por el " " da error (Cuando no lo tiene).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente --justo lo que buscaba !